# Embedded google form defaulting to center on mobile display

Tags: css

I have embedded a google form on my website here: https://gymefit.tw/groupclasssignup/

On the mobile view of this page in safari it seems to be defaulting to the center.  I tried to fix it with CSS but have not had any luck

I've tried a bunch of stuff on css but am still a bit new so I think I am missing something here.

```
<div class="group">
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSep0dl_-1LARR9R0ZVwrDz9Wy7rFI0cbxp6ckT6xAZFgLyLhQ/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="4303">
</iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.group iframe {
text-align:left !important;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without a bit more info. Is this only on safari, or other mobile browsers? Are these mobile devices in portrait or landscape mode? Are you familiar with @media queries, and if so, have you used any?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett its on all safari ipad and iphone devices - havent tried anything else.  There arent any media queries.  I am using the Zelle Pro template - so that may be overriding it or google is?

Comment: OK. And sorry, what is it about the centering that's happening that is bothering you? Is it the whole form that is being pushed to the center, or just the text in the form?

Comment: I'm not too experienced with templates, so I can't speak to what they may be overriding, however, I have a few things  you can try. I've read that safari sometimes doesn't like `auto` values (which is the default for many things) and that others have reported that adding a `min-width:0` has been enough for safari to apply the correct alignments to things. So, first thing to try is to create a class for just `iframe` and give it a `min-width:0;`. You could also put `text-align:left;` in there just for the hell of it to see if it makes any difference. If not, I might have 1 or 2 more ideas